# Regular expression matching if the pattern is in the beginning of a sentence, the end of a sentence is is surrounded by white space

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regular expression in java to try and find if the pattern is either in the beginning of a string, at the end of the string, or surrounded by white space but it is not working.

If I do this `\\Wmypattern\\W` it finds patterns surrounded by white space.

But if I do this `[^\\W]mypattern[\\W$]` it does not.   The latter regular expression is my attempt to get it to match if pattern exists in the beginning of the string, the end of the string or starts at the beginning or ends at the end of string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

```
(^|\\W)mypattern(\\W|$)
```

This will match *either* a non-word character or the beginning of the string at the beginning of the pattern and *either* a non-word character or the end of the string at the end of the pattern.

Your current pattern matches a single character that is not a non-word character (`[^\\W]`) followed by your pattern, and followed by either a non-word character or the literal character `$` (`[\\W$]`)

[This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is a good reference for regular expression syntax

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `^` and `$` outside the `[]`.  You are escaping it now.

By specifying `[\\W]mypattern[\\W]` it means surrounded by non-word characters.  I think you want to use `[\\s]`, a whitespace character.  See [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for more information.

If you want to match at the beginning or end, you'll have to do something like this:

```
^mypattern: beginning of the string
mypattern$: end of the string
```

Comment: Actually, `^` in a character set has a special meaning (negation) and putting it outside will make it an "and" condition instead of an "or" condition